# Weibull Non-exceedance plot (axis 'x')

Tags: python, statsmodels, weibull

I am working on the Weibull distribution. I've estimated the parameters for my data and I've got the probability plot. As seen in the code bellow, on the probability plot I have 'pasted' the parameter values that I obtained.

But, is **there any other way to attach them to the plot?**

Another question is: how can I get a plot with the **probability of non-exceedance on axis 'x'** and the variable on axis 'y', which, in turn, i**ncludes the weibull** adjustment with the three parameters. The **plot** I'm looking for **is like this** (or similar).

[Weibull Non-exceedance curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlHkp.png)

The code in python I wrote is the next:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('classic')
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import exponweib, probplot as pp, weibull_min
import probscale
from probscale.viz import probplot as pp_scale, plot_pos
import statsmodels.distributions
from scipy.optimize import fmin
import statsmodels.api as sm

datos = pd.read_csv('01_ATN_ACCE_his_1985_2005.csv')
Hs = datos['Hs']
plt.hist(Hs, density = True, alpha = 0.5, bins=45)
shape, loc, scale = weibull_min.fit(Hs)
x = np.linspace(Hs.min(), Hs.max(), 500)
plt.plot(x, weibull_min(shape, loc, scale).pdf(x))
plt.xlabel("Hs (m)")
plt.ylabel("%")
plt.title("Ajuste Weibull sobre Hs")
fig, ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
pp(Hs, dist = weibull_min(shape, loc, scale), fit=True, plot=ax, rvalue=True)
plt.text(0.5,7,'A=', fontsize=14)
plt.text(0.7,7,'{0:.2f}'.format(scale), fontsize=14)
plt.text(0.5, 6.5, 'B=', fontsize=14)
plt.text(0.7,6.5,'{0:.2f}'.format(loc), fontsize=14)
plt.text(0.5, 6, 'C=', fontsize=14)
plt.text(0.7,6,'{0:.2f}'.format(shape), fontsize=14)
ax.get_children()[2].set_fontsize(14) 
ax.get_children()[2].set_position((0.5,5.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

Without access to your data set it is not possible to replicate your script.

The image you attached has probability on the x-axis and velocity on the y-axis. This almost looks like a [probability plot](https://reliability.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Probability%20plots.html#example-1) with the x and y axes swapped.

I recommend you plot the probability plot format (probability on the y axis) as this is much more common and available in several software applications.

Within Python you might consider using [reliability](https://reliability.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to fit your probability distribution and produce your probability plot. While *reliability* is designed for reliability engineering, the "failures" can really be anything so your velocity data will be fine (provided it is non-negative if fitting a Weibull distribution).